# php crashes and rdp is not available

Tags: php, windows, apache

I become allways this error message in event logger from windows diagnostics.
PHP crashes and after is the server via RDP not available.. any reason?

- Faulting application name: php.EXE, version: 5.6.8.0, time stamp: 0x552ee168
- Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18798, time stamp: 0x5507b3e0
- Exception code: 0xc0000005
- Fault offset: 0x000326d1
- Faulting process id: 0xa3c
- Faulting application start time: 0x01d0d55d7c6ee552
- Faulting application path: D:\php\56-win32-VC11-NTS\php.EXE
- Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll

Best regards

Comment: Did you found a solution? I have this too

Comment: what is you operating system version ?

Answer (score 3):

`ntdll.dll` is one of the kernel drivers for Microsoft Windows. There are a variety of fixes proposed for dealing with this issue, most of which appear to come down to either reinstalling the offending application (in this case php and your web server) or reinstalling `ntdll.dll` and/or reregistering it.

Comment: Can the ntdll.dll be damaged because of windows updates? That was the only change done manually on the server, since this msg came up

Comment: ntdll.dll can be damaged by application installations, virus attacks and by windows OS crash or power loss. Microsoft recommends that if either of the two latter events occur (OS crash or power loss), that a full disk scan be performed to identify, isolate and if possible repair damaged files. I don't know if a successfully completed Windows update would damage that file, but the other items listed can damage it.